# Boostrap Yamm Navbar glitchy on hover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm currently re-designing a website for a charity, using a YAMM Navbar with Bootstrap, and i have the strange situation that if i test just the Navbar & CSS code on Bootply it works great - but when putting it on my webserver, it goes all glitchy with the 'hover effect' (so the Navbar drops down on hover).
In terms of 'glitchy' (on my webserver) the menu drops down on hover, but when you move the mouse down to the dropped down menu - it instantly disappears.

To semi convince myself its not an issue with my hosted Web Server, i also ran it on a LAMP Stack VM, and the same thing happens.
But on Bootply, the code works perfect, & doesn't have the 'glitch'.

So first, here's a link to Bootply where the Navbar hover works fine;
[Bootply code](https://www.bootply.com/2ZjMOBDeNn)

Here's a link to the site on my WebServer (where the Navbar is glitchy on hover):
[WebServer](http://bliss.net.au/Open-New/#/)

And here's the actual code to my Index page (note - the site uses Angular, with the Index, so its just the header & footer being used as a Template.  Also note, that it does contain alot of legacy code, which will be cleaned up once the site is done).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app='myApp'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX, FOLLOW">
    <meta name="Keywords" content="OpenHouse Christian Involvement Centre, OpenHouse, Christian, Involvement, Centre, Melbourne, Macleod">
    <meta name="description" content="Open House, Christian Involvement Centres">
    <meta name="author" content="*******">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="Wp-AVOainmBYwLoJRfZ4dZif0GWjK4wZYGK8WbBOZ8k" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

    <title>Open House</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/nanogallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/nanogallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/nanogallery_clean.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- nanoGALLERY - css file for the theme 'light'                                                                         -->
      <link href="css/nanogallery_light.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Yamm styles-->
    <link href="css/yamm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Lightbox Gallery (for Youtube Videos) - css files -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.1.1/ekko-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.1.1/ekko-lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- BXslider - css file -->
    <link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Animate CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" />-->

    <!-- Basic Smooth jquery Accordion -->
    <!--<link href="css/jquery.bbAccordion.css" rel="stylesheet">-->


    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- ===== Google Fonts ===== -->
    <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calligraffitti|Kaushan+Script|Sofia" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette" rel="stylesheet">

<!--</head>-->

<!--<body>-->
<style>
/* ==== Custom CSS for the Donations Button ==== */
/*#donationBtn:hover, #donationBtn:focus, #donationBtn:active {color: #337ab7 !important;}*/
#donationBtn:hover, #donationBtn:focus, #donationBtn:active {background-color: #225e91 !important;}

#lnkMail {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
}

/* menu styes */
/*.list-unstyled,
.list-unstyled ul { min-width: 120px }

@media ( min-width: 767px ) {
  .panel-group { width: 400px; }
  .thumbnail { margin: 0; }
}*/

/* === Footer === */
.copyright {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  font-size: 0.8em;
  letter-spacing: 0.225em;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.copyright-icons {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  /*padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;*/
}

 .copyright-icons a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

 .copyright-icons a:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }

/* Footer */

    #footer {
        padding: 6em 0 4em 0 ;
        background-color: #1d242a;
        text-align: center;
    }

        #footer .icons {
            font-size: 1.25em;
        }

            #footer .icons a {
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
            }

                #footer .icons a:hover {
                    color: #fff;
                }

        #footer .copyright {
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
            font-size: 0.8em;
            letter-spacing: 0.225em;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

            #footer .copyright li {
                border-left: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
                display: inline-block;
                line-height: 1em;
                margin-left: 1em;
                padding-left: 1em;
            }

                #footer .copyright li:first-child {
                    border-left: 0;
                    margin-left: 0;
                    padding-left: 0;
                }

                #footer .copyright li a {
                    color: inherit;
                }

                    #footer .copyright li a:hover {
                        color: #fff;
                    }

                @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

                    #footer .copyright li {
                        border: 0;
                        display: block;
                        line-height: 1.65em;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0.5em 0;
                    }

                }

        @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

            #footer {
                padding: 4em 3em 2em 3em ;
            }

        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 736px) {

            #footer {
                padding: 3em 2em 1em 2em ;
            }

        }

/*.navbar {
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}*/

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, transparent); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(white, transparent); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, transparent); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(white, rgba(255,255,255,0.3)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  /*color: #337ab7 !important;*/
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

/*
.navbar-default {
  color: #000000 !important;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}

.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    left: 10px;
    top: 11px;
    left: -6px;
} */

/*.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    background-image: none;
}*/

/* ==== Custom Change for Navbar Collapse ==== */
/*@media (max-width: 994px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(51,102,153,0.1);
        background-color: white;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
            top: 0;
            border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
            margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}*/
.yamm .nav, .yamm .collapse, .yamm .dropup, .yamm .dropdown {
   position: static;
}

.yamm .container {
   position: relative;
}

.yamm .dropdown-menu {
   left: auto;
}

.yamm .yamm-content {
  padding: 3px 15px 3px;
}

.yamm .yamm-content .a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.nounderline {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}

a.nounderline:hover {
  color: #225e91;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #225e91;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #225e91;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: none;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #225e91;
}

/*.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown:hover > a:focus {
    background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
}*/

/*li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}*/

@media (min-width: 979px) {
  ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

/*.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  color: #225e91;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: none !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > li:hover {
  background-color: none !important;
}*/


img.centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ============ START NAVBAR =========== -->
  <nav class="navbar yamm navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
         <!--<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Yamm Megamenu</a>-->
           <!--<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>-->
         <a href="#/" class="pull-left"><img src="images/logo-new.png" alt="Open House logo"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right;">

          <!-- Home Menu -->
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><strong>Home</strong><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
              <li><a href="documents/Newsletters/Newsletter_June_2017.pdf" target="_blank">Latest News</a></li>
              <li><a href="#events">Coming Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#involved">Get Involved</a></li>
              <li><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ceo">CEO Message</a></li>
              <li><a href="#bibleRead">Bible Reading</a></li>
              <li><a href="#pray">Pray For Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

           <!-- About Us Menu -->
           <!-- Classic list -->
           <!-- Classic list -->
             <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"><a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><strong>About Us</strong><b class="caret"></b></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li>
                   <!-- Content container to add padding -->
                   <div class="yamm-content">
                     <div class="row">
                       <ul class="col-lg-4 list-unstyled" style="line-height:1.42857143;">
                         <li>
                           <h4 style="color:#225e91;"><strong>Who We Are</strong></h4>
                         </li>
                         <li ><a href="#origins" class="nounderline" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;">Our Origins</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#ourhistory" class="nounderline" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;">Our History</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#what" class="nounderline">What We Do</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#why" class="nounderline">Why We Do It</a></li>
                         <li><a href="documents/Strategic_Plan-promotional.pdf" target="_blank" class="nounderline">Strategic Plan</a></li>

                       </ul>
                       <ul class="col-lg-4 list-unstyled">
                         <li>
                           <h4 style="color:#225e91;"><strong>Our People</strong></h4>
                         </li>
                         <li><a href="#board" class="nounderline">Our Board</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#team" class="nounderline">Our Team</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#volunteers" class="nounderline">Volunteers</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#supporters" class="nounderline">Supporters</a></li>
                       </ul>
                       <ul class="col-lg-4 list-unstyled">
                         <li>
                           <h4 style="color:#225e91;"><strong>Resources</strong></h4>
                         </li>
                         <li><a href="#photos" class="nounderline">Photos</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#videos" class="nounderline">Videos</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#books" class="nounderline">Book</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#reports" class="nounderline">Annual Reports</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#newsletter" class="nounderline">News Letters</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#jobs" class="nounderline">Job Vacancies</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#policies" class="nounderline">Policies</a></li>
                       </ul>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </li>

          <!-- Programs Menu -->
          <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"><a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><strong>Programs</strong><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li>
                <div class="yamm-content">
                  <div class="row">
                    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-unstyled" style="line-height:1.42857143;">
                      <li>
                        <h4 style="color:#225e91;"><strong>Children & Youth</strong></h4>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#mothers" class="nounderline">Play Group</a></li>
                      <li><a data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#holiday" class="nounderline" title="School Holiday Program">School Holiday Program</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#boys" class="nounderline">Boys 2 Men</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#girls" class="nounderline">Fun 4 Girls</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#teens" class="nounderline">Drop In Cafe</a></li>
                      <li><a data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#youth" class="nounderline" title="Youth Workshop Mentoring Program">Youth Workshop Mentoring Program</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#backyard" class="nounderline">Backyard Sports</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#bike" class="nounderline">Bike Hut</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-unstyled" style="line-height:1.42857143;">
                      <li>
                        <h4 style="color:#225e91;"><strong>Adults</strong></h4>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#bibleFellow" class="nounderline">Bible Fellowship</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#clubwork" class="nounderline">Clubwork</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#arts" class="nounderline">Arts and Crafts</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#meal" class="nounderline">Community Meal</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#individual" class="nounderline">Individual Support</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#mens" class="nounderline">Mens Support Group</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#adult" class="nounderline">Adult Workshops</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

           <!-- Testimonials Menu -->
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><b>Testimonials </b><span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#participants">Participants</a></li>
              <li><a href="#caregive">Care Givers</a></li>
              <!--<li><a href="#sponsors">Our Sponsors</a></li>-->
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#links"><b>Useful links </b></a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact"><b>Contact Us </b></a></li>
          <li><a href="#donations" id="donationBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:-25px; !important; color: #ffffff;"><b> Donations </b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- ============ END NAVBAR =========== -->

<!--<script>
//$('a').tooltip();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>-->

<!-- ==== Navbar Scroll Change ==== -->
<div id="startchange"></div>


<div data-ng-view></div>

<!-- ========= START FOOTER ========== -->
<!--<footer id="footer">
                        <ul class="icons">
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/WiznuForHair/" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/wiznuforhair/" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-envelope-o"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="copyright">
                            <li>&copy; 2017, Open House CIC </li><li>Design: <a href="http://www.bliss.net.au">Bliss</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </footer>-->

<footer class="footer" style="padding: 6em 0 4em 0; background-color: #1d242a;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
        <a href="http://www.acnc.gov.au/" target="_blank">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/ACNC-Charity-Logo.png" alt="ACNC Charity" width="100" height="100"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="blank-gap-20"></div>
        <a href="http://www.qip.com.au/" target="_blank">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/QIP-logo.png" alt="QIP logo" width="125"></a>
      </div>

      <!--<div class="visible-sm visible-xs clearfix"></div>-->
      <!--<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-center">
        <h4><strong>Join Us</strong></h4>
        <ul class='list-unstyled'>
          <li style="float: left; padding-left:50px; padding-right:5px;"><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClFV3cZ3_e4u3O0zEmYun3w" title="YouTube" target="_blank">
            <img class="center-block centered" src="images/icons/youtube.png" width="30"><a></li>
          <li style="float: left; padding-right:5px;"><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="https://www.facebook.com/openhousecic/" title="facebook" target="_blank">
            <img class="center-block centered" src="images/icons/facebook.png" width="30"></a></li>
          <li style="float: left; padding-right:5px;"><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/open-house-cic" title="LinkedIn" target="_blank">
            <img class="center-block centered" src="images/icons/linkedin.jpg" width="30"></a></li>
          <li style="float: left; padding-right:5px;"><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/146218711@N02" title="flickr" target="_blank">
            <img class="center-block centered" src="images/icons/Flickr.png" width="30"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>-->

      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
        <a href="https://www.ndis.gov.au/" target="_blank">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/NDIS-logo.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
      </div>

      <!--<div class="col-lg-1"></div>-->
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center copyright">
        <div class="copyright-icons">
          <span><i><a href="https://www.facebook.com/openhousecic/" class="icon fa fa-facebook"><!--<span class="label">Facebook</span>--></a></i>
          <i><a href="https://www.instagram.com/wiznuforhair/" class="icon fa fa-flickr"><!--<span class="label">Instagram</span>--></a></i>
          <i><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/open-house-cic" class="icon fa fa-linkedin"></a></i>
          <i><a href="#" class="icon fa fa-envelope-o"><!--<span class="label">Email</span>--></a></i></span>
          </div>
        <span>&copy; 2017, Open House Christian Involvement Centres : Website by <a href="http://www.bliss.net.au" target="_blank">Bliss</a></span>
        <div class="blank-gap-10"></div>
        <p><i>We acknowledge and pay respect to the Traditional Owners of the lands upon which Open House Christian Involvement Centres are situated.</i><p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>-->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-csv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/navbar-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/email-spam.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>wow = new WOW({}).init();</script>

    <!-- NANOGallery Javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nanogallery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nanogallery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Lightbox Gallery Javascript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.1.1/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.1.1/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script scr="js/jquery.bbAccordion.js"></script>-->

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    </script>

  <script>
     $(function() {
       window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()
       $(document).on('click', '.yamm .dropdown-menu', function(e) {
         e.stopPropagation()
       })
     })
   </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logo is too big.

Or your navbar is too small.

That's pretty much it. On your actual site you are loading a logo that is taller than your navbar, so when you hover over your navbar item, the menu loads below the navbar, but when you move your mouse down your mouse exits the navbar item, so it thinks you've just moved away.

I've forked your Bootply - https://www.bootply.com/Pk3KFvr0RL - But actually included your logo so you can see the problem.

There's a few things you can do. You can make your logo smaller, or you can increase the size of your nav items so they fill the whole area. A simple way to do this would be to change your `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` in the `.navbar-nav>li>a` rule to `20px`. There are probably better ways of making it more responsive (in case you change the height of the logo etc.) but this is just a quick fix, feel free to find a better way.

Comment: Thanks heaps #Rob Quincey;
I feel really stupid after a mistake like that :-)